# Bash script to start spring-boot app and finish script

Tags: bash, deployment, spring-boot

I have a bash script to deploy my spring-boot app (using bamboo).

script gets hung on this as the spring-boot app launches and is running

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

I tried running it in the background with

```
java -jar myApp.jar &
```

as well as

```
java -jar myApp.jar &
disown
```

just "&" seems to do nothing while the "&" followed by "disown" made the script fail.

How do I let the script finish while the spring-boot app keeps running?

Comment: `just "&" seems to do nothing` is not actually true, it actually runs the app in the background and lets the script run to completion. How do you claim it does nothing?

Comment: If `java -jar myApp.jar` on it's own for sure works, and does what you want it to do, then putting `java -jar myApp.jar &` in a bash script will run your app in the background and the rest of the bash script will continue, I don't see the problem.  Post some output to show us the problem and what's happening, and also tell us what you expect to happen.

Comment: I didn't claim that it does nothing. I claimed that it seemed to do nothing - because it seemed to do nothing. Just putting the "&" at the end, the script was still waiting on the java call to finish (which wont because it is starting a service). I added ">> /dev/null" before the "&" and it seemed to do the trick. The script now starts the app and completes itself

Answer (score 8):

There is multiple options, one as mentioned is 'nohup' command. Another way to run is using 'screen' virtual terminal. But I would suggest you take a considerably better approach and run it as any other background service on *nix machines (like apache, mysql, etc.)

Here my very simple code that I have inside of `/etc/init.d/great-spring-boot-app` script, you can edit few lines to suite your conventions and save this file with 
any name inside of /etc/init.d/ directory, for example `/etc/init.d/my-cool-spring-boot-app`

Then make it executable:
 `chmod +x /etc/init.d/my-cool-spring-boot-app`

Afterwards can simply start process by doing something like

`sudo service my-cool-spring-boot-app start`

Other options are:

`stop|restart|status`

```
#!/bin/bash -

#=-= START OF CUSTOM SERVICE CONFIGURATION =-#
# Where micro service war/jar file sits?
MS_HOME=/opt/MY_MICRO_SERVICE_ROOT_DIRECTORY # <--- EDIT THIS LINE

# Actual file name of Micro Service (jar or war), 
# ms-service.war or something-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, etc.
MS_JAR=MY_SPRING_BOOT_APPLICATION-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war # <--- EDIT THIS LINE
# ^^^ that should relative to MS_HOME directory.

# Which username we should run as.
RUNASUSER=USER_TO_RUN_AS; # <-- EDIT THIS LINE, 
# if port number for spring boot is < 1024 it needs root perm.

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_60; # <-- EDIT THIS, Where is your JDK/JRE?
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH};
SHUTDOWN_WAIT=20; # before issuing kill -9 on process.

export PATH JAVA_HOME


# These options are used when micro service is starting 
# Add whatever you want/need here... overrides application*.yml.
OPTIONS="
-Dserver.port=8080
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
";
#=-= END OF CUSTOM CONFIGURATION =-=#

# Try to get PID of spring jar/war
MS_PID=`ps fax|grep java|grep "${MS_JAR}"|awk '{print $1}'`
export MS_PID;

# Function: run_as
run_as() {
    local iam iwant;

    iam=$(id -nu);
    iwant="$1";
    shift;

    if [ "${iam}" = "${iwant}" ]; then {
    eval $*;
    }
    else {
    /bin/su -p -s /bin/sh ${iwant} $*;
    } fi;
}

# Function: start
start() {
  pid=${MS_PID}
  if [ -n "${pid}" ]; then {
    echo "Micro service is already running (pid: ${pid})";
  }
  else {
    # Start screener ms
    echo "Starting micro service";
    cd $MS_HOME
    run_as ${RUNASUSER} java -jar ${OPTIONS} ./${MS_JAR};
    # java -jar ${OPTIONS} ./${MS_JAR}
  } fi;
  # return 0;
}

# Function: stop
stop() {
  pid=${MS_PID}
  if [ -n "${pid}" ]; then {

    run_as ${RUNASUSER} kill -TERM $pid

    echo -ne "Stopping micro service module";

    kwait=${SHUTDOWN_WAIT};

    count=0;
    while kill -0 ${pid} 2>/dev/null && [ ${count} -le ${kwait} ]; do {
      printf ".";
      sleep 1;
      (( count++ ));
    } done;

    echo;

    if [ ${count} -gt ${kwait} ]; then {
      printf "process is still running after %d seconds, killing process" \
    ${SHUTDOWN_WAIT};
      kill ${pid};
      sleep 3;

      # if it's still running use kill -9
      #
      if kill -0 ${pid} 2>/dev/null; then {
        echo "process is still running, using kill -9";
        kill -9 ${pid}
        sleep 3;
      } fi;
    } fi;

    if kill -0 ${pid} 2>/dev/null; then {
      echo "process is still running, I give up";
    } 
    else {
      # success, delete PID file, if you have used it with spring boot
      # rm -f ${SPRING_BOOT_APP_PID};
    } fi;
  } 
  else {
      echo "Micro service is not running";
  } fi;

  #return 0;
}

# Main Code

case $1 in
  start)
    start;
    ;;
  stop)
    stop;
    ;;
  restart)
    stop;
    sleep 1;
    start;
    ;;
  status)
    pid=$MS_PID
    if [ "${pid}" ]; then {
      echo "Micro service module is running with pid: ${pid}";
    }
    else {
      echo "Micro service module is not running";
    } fi;
    ;;
esac

exit 0;
```

This is the appropriate way to start background service(s) on Linux.

Comment: Why you didn't use the no hub ?

Answer (score 4):

`nohup java -jar myApp.jar &`

`nohup` will intercept the `HUP` (hangup) signal when the TTY closes. This prevents the process from being terminated when the user logs out / your remote session ends. The ampersand is for  starting the process in the background.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Easy stop / start spring boot application uber jar
https://github.com/tyrion9/spring-boot-startup-script

Copy uber jar file in the same folder

```
./bootstrap.sh start
./bootstrap.sh stop
./bootstrap.sh restart
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using start and shutdown scripts

I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63330194/2557818).

You could use a set of scripts to achieve this. For example a `startup.sh` may look like this. It will start the application and write the process id to `/path/to/app/pid.file` .And the `nohup` disowns the process so the process doesn't hold on to current `TTY` session.

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar /path/to/app/hello-world.jar > /path/to/log.txt 2>&1 &
echo $! > /path/to/app/pid.file
```

And a `shutdown.sh` may look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
kill $(cat /path/to/app/pid.file)
```

You can find more detail in my post. https://springhow.com/start-stop-scripts-for-spring-boot-applications/