# Starting Spring boot applications from script

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Using normal spring mvn commands, I can start a spring boot application from command line and terminate it with Control+c. I however have created a bunch of services which I will dockerize later. For now they are plain java jar files generated by mvn. How do I use a python script or a Bash script to start them one by one and then use a script to terminate them. Is there some way where i start it and script won't block and the app will have a name that i can later use to stop the app?

Answer (score 5):

I would follow the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) to install `Spring-Boot` application as a `Unix/Linux` service.

All you have to do is to add this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After adding the plugin you should install and create a symlink to your application ([exact part of documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service)):

> Assuming that you have a Spring Boot application installed in
>   `/var/myapp`, to install a Spring Boot application as an init.d service
>   simply create a symlink:
>
> `$ sudo ln -s /var/myapp/myapp.jar /etc/init.d/myapp`
>
> Once installed,
>   you can start and stop the service in the usual way. For example, on a
>   Debian based system:
>
> `$ service myapp start`

Then you are able to create a bash script to `start`, `stop` or `restart` your applications in a clean way.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a script to achieve this. For example a `startup.sh` may look like this. It will start the application and write the process id to `/path/to/app/pid.file`

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar /path/to/app/hello-world.jar > /path/to/log.txt 2>&1 &
echo $! > /path/to/app/pid.file
```

And a `shutdown.sh` may look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
kill $(cat /path/to/app/pid.file)
```

You can find more detail in my post. https://springhow.com/start-stop-scripts-for-spring-boot-applications/

Answer (score 1):

#### You can launch each jar with the following command (in a bash script):

```
java -jar service1.jar &
```

#### Then, you can kill each process with the following command (in a bash script):

```
pkill -f service1.jar
```

`pkill` will terminates all processes containing the provided name. Be careful that your keyword only identifies your process, so you don't terminate other processes by mistake.

Comment: what is the "&" for at the end of start script?

Answer (score 0):

This script make it easy, auto find newest version of jar file:

https://github.com/tyrion9/spring-boot-startup-script

```
./bootstrap.sh start
./bootstrap.sh stop
./bootstrap.sh restart
```